# Getting error while trying to move documentset from one library to other using PnP powershell

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell, document-set

I have a requirement to move the document set(documents inside) from one library to other within the same site, maintaining all  metadata and  versions in destination library as well.

I tried below PnP Powershell code:

Move-PnPFile -SiteRelativeUrl "DocLib1/SampleDocSet" -TargetUrl "/sites/ITDDEV2/DocLib2"

Getting error  :"Cannot rename "SampleDocSet" to "DocLib2": destination already exists".

Can anyone help me on this error?

Comment: Try solution given [here](https://andrewwarland.wordpress.com/2022/08/02/using-pnp-powershell-to-move-folders-and-document-sets-in-sharepoint-online/). Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: `Move-PnPFile` cmdlet does not overwrite existing files or folders by default. You should specify the full path of the document set in the target URL.

Comment: Hi Martin, I'm trying to move(Cut and paste) a document set(SampleDocSet)  from DocLib1 into a document library(DocLib2) .Not moving inside a document set  hence I gave target url   Document library (DocLib2) path.